# What are the younger and aged Unknowns triggering in the Power Plant?

Tags: plot-explanation, dark

In the series *Dark*, we are already shown that in Adam's world, the Apocalypse of 2020 was triggered by Adam in 1920. When Clausen orders for the concrete section to be busted open, he exposes the radioactive material that is then activated by what Adam and his team are doing in 1920. The end results in the Apocalypse of 2020 in Adam's world.

In Eve's world, we are shown The Unknown entering the power plant and rigging it to create the Apocalypse in 2019. The younger and older self of The Unknown land up in an alternate world power plant and rig something.

My question is:
What are the young and old Unknown doing? They have no role to play in Adam world's apocalypse, yet they are there doing something.

EDIT: I'm looking to get answers from the Series and not from the website.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read and saw in the show, they actually do have a role to play in the Apocalypse in both worlds.

For one thing, all of their actions are just to get the cycle to repeat again, so their goal is to basically know their place in the timeline and follow it.

In this case, from what I understand, they are creating the nuclear incident in both worlds which lead to the creation of the "God particle", which allowed for several forms of time travel.  If the nuclear power plant didn't have an incident in 1986, there wouldn't have been buried barrels of waste for Clausen to dig up in 2020 either.  Without them causing that incident, many events in the show could not have occurred.

On the [Official Dark Website](https://darknetflix.io/), this is all explained when you look at the Unknown on the family tree and scroll through events, one is this:

[image: Dark Website explaination]

Which explains the same set of events.

Comment: The apocalypses are in 2020 and 2019 in the two worlds. The God Particle event is in 1986 in both worlds. If we assume the Man went to 2019 to rig the power plant, then the Young and Aged land up in 2020. We are shown in a previous season that the 2020 apocalypse was triggered by Adam in 1920. He triggers the God Particle because Clausen has the concrete broken. The Young and Aged seem unnecessary for the 2020 Apocalypse as Adam is already causing it.

Comment: Summary:
The God Particle is created in 1986.
This is not when The Unknowns go. They go to the moments of the Apocalypse (2019 & 2020).
The Unknown are not responsible for the creation of the God Particle. H.G. Tannhaus' experiment in the Origin World in 1986 is the thing that causes the explosion and God Particle in 1986 in both worlds.

Comment: @MovieMe Did you even read my answer?  The Unkowns travel to 1986 to trigger the creation of the God Particle, _not_ to trigger the actual apocalypse in each power plant.  The official website actually goes over all these details.  https://imgur.com/a/HgaEb29  They trigger the accident, the accident creates the God Particle, the God Particle causes each apocalypse.

Comment: a quick question here. If the Unknowns were responsible for the Accident of 86, Why does Claudia tell Adam that H.G. Tannhaus' experiment in the Origin World causes the explosion (accident?) of 1986?

Comment: is there any mention in the series that the date they go back to is 1986? As I watched, there were no dates mentioned. I understand the website gives additional information, but I'm looking at this from the series' perspective.

Comment: @MovieMe Tannhaus causes an accident in _his_ 1986 that ends the origin world in 1986, and creates the two worlds the show focuses on.  I'm not sure if the show specifically calls it out as 1986, though the set for the power plant looks pretty 1986 to me.  I think it's more about connecting the pieces there, knowing that something went wrong at the power plant in 1986, and no one seemed to know what caused it, until we learn that they steal the master keys and go mess with the plant.

Comment: Thanks. The Volume Control Manual gives it away as to what their intention was. This is the process of waste material exit. Please remove the entry from the website. Accepted your answer, this just created a bigger question now - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/110072/what-caused-these-events-in-dark

Comment: I can't say this enough, but that website is filling in for far too much information than the series bothers showing. The Unknowns were last seen with Martha in 2019. The adult Unknown is seen sending off the child and aged though the portal. This would lead one to assume that the Adult stayed back in 2019. The end of series couldn't have been rushed any further. They knew they rushed it so they put up that website to patch all the gaps.

Comment: @MovieMe I'm not going to _remove_ the link to the official website.  It explains exactly what happened.  Yes, I also think it's unfortunate that a lot of the clearest information about what is happening comes from the website and not from the show itself; but I didn't write either of them.  It's really not my fault that the website is more explicit than the show, which just implies a lot of these things.

Comment: if you notice, I had updated earlier my question for answers from the series and not the website. I understand you are only quoting it, but I'm looking for answers only from the series. For the consistency of other readers I was asking you to remove it because it would confuse. But it's totally your choice to leave it there. Cheers.

Comment: @MovieMe Just so you're aware, the website just catalogues and explains all the information from the series.  It's not really presenting new information, it's just basically making it way easier to follow each plot line and removes some of the ambiguity of how it was presented.

Comment: the reason why I prefer to not have an answer from the website is I'd like to know what the pieces of the puzzle were and how they connect to form the answer. While the site presents the answer and it might seemingly answer my question, I want to know the path to the answer via information from various episodes. The devil lies in the details. :)

Comment: @MovieMe, I agree with what you're saying about the site. It's like those puzzles in the newspaper. Sure you can flip the paper upside down and read the final answer. But then there is the "why is that the answer?" and there is a solution to get to that answer. The whole excitement is finding that solution, not just knowing the answer.

Comment: @MovieMe In this case though it was mostly you asking about pieces of the puzzle that you were putting together incorrectly, and I was just explaining what actually happened.  You incorrectly assumed that one set was in 2019 causing the apocalypse directly.  You weren't really asking how we knew they were in 1986, because you had assumed they weren't; so my answer didn't focus on how we would know that.

Comment: @JMac, Yes, I had wrongly assumed that the Unknowns traveled back in time to trigger the apocalypse. They only went back to cause the leak. We know from the series that they caused the leak because they steal the Volume Control Manual. This is the Chemical Volume & Control manual which has information on contaminant management. That containment is the radioactive substance they try to hide. In the scene were The Unknowns enter the PP, we are again show the sign board for Volume Control panel. This tells us that they are in 1986 as the scene doesn't put a date unlike the others in the episode.

Comment: That date 21st Jul 1986. I don't know if it is ever mentioned in the series. Claudia, in Nov 1986 takes over and says 3 months ago there was an incident. When Jonas talks to H.G. Tannhaus about the time machine, he also only says a *few months before*. The site does catalog the information from the series, but surely adds some definitive information not shown in the show too.