# What caused these events in DARK?

Tags: plot-explanation, dark

How did the Apocalypse of 2020 and 2019 take place? What caused it and why did they happen at two different dates considering the waste leaks were triggered on the same date by The Unknowns in 1986?

I'm looking for answers from the series and not the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unknown triggered a nuclear incident in 1986 in both worlds.  This created the "God particle" (Cesium-137 is what the Stranger calls it).  This in itself does not seem to cause the apocalypse, though like every event in the series, is a necessary component.

**Straightforward, but possibly unsatisfying answer:**

The trigger for the actual apocalypse in each case appears to be opening the yellow barrels in the power plant.  It almost *seems* like just leaving the barrels open for awhile is what triggers it, but I think it's more complicated than that.  The only thing I am sure of is that opening the barrels (once by Clausen in Jonas' world, the other time by Aleksander in Eve's world) is definitely a component to the apocalypse in each case.

**My own speculation (ignore this if you don't want interpretations of the series):**

I want to speculate more on why I think it occurs at those times, and it isn't just as simple as opening the barrels.  I think it's somewhat important that it requires more than just opening the barrels, since we actually see Jonas ("the Stranger") open a barrel in season 1 episode 9 on the trucks, and it doesn't cause an apocalypse.

I think if we look at the bigger picture, the two important factors are location and time.

Because of the cyclical nature of everything in the two worlds, the timing of the event may be almost predetermined.  If it does not happen at the specific time in each world, then some events would not happen the same, and thus events wouldn't have led to that situation at all.

I think this is even further supported when we think of the locations of the events.  The barrels only seem to trigger the apocalypse when opened from the inside of the power plant, in the same room on each world it seems.  After the apocalypse, a remnant of the portal remains, which then gets manipulated for time travel by various people who lead to the apocalypse in the first place.  The apocalypse also seems to tie in with the "loopholes" which get exploited a few times to create diverging realities.

In full speculation on my part, due to the cycle, there might be something special about opening the barrels at those specific locations and times which triggers the apocalypse.

It's a bit of a chicken and egg scenario all around.  Does the loop cause the loophole, or does the loophole cause the loops/apocalypse in the first place?  I don't really know if there's a clear answer, it seems to be a fundamental part of the cyclical nature of time travel that the apocalypses must occur at the times and locations they occur.

Comment: To extend your speculation, which I think is on the right track, there is always _someone_ causing a trigger in one of the time periods. Since the God particle travels time, triggering it in one time period affects the other times. Adam knew when to trigger it based on when the barrels would be opened in 2019, so he triggers it exactly a multiple of 33 years removed from that 2019-barrel-opening event. It's sort of like a telephone call. One person makes the call but all connected phones ring. Someone who stands by one of the other phones would also ask "how the phone was activated".

Comment: @Flater. Yes, that scene of the 2020 apocalypse is shown with three events. The Barrel opening, Magus and Franziska triggering their portal, Elsisabeth in 2053 doing something in the power plant. However that said, there are no other concurrent events for the 2019 apocalypse of Eve's World. There is no Adam in that world.

Comment: So as @JMac suggests it might just be opening the barrel in a specific spot.

Comment: @MovieMe: Doesn't Adam kill pregnant alt-Martha around the same time? As he's slated to go to Eve next to kill her (cfr their last scene where he surprisingly didn't have bullets in the gun), he could've already been in the alt-power plant, both triggering the apocalypse and killing pregnant alt-Martha with the same portal. He even _says_ that killing Martha is done to repeat the cycle, which the apocalypse also accomplishes.

Comment: @flater, I'm not sure how Adams actions in 2054 connect with the apocalypse. Elisabeth, months earlier, already was at the point where the wormhole opened up. That instant is when the apocalypse is just about to take place. All the scenes in the future appear to be in Adams World. Eve's world had nothing but the cave left in a desert like condition. I'm not sure the series gives any information regarding 2054 in Eve's world but for one scene.

Comment: @MovieMe Specific spot and specific time.  For opening the barrels to have the right effect, all the pieces need to be in place, so if you tried to open the barrel at the wrong time, I suspect it either wouldn't work, or would totally screw up the loop.

Comment: @JMac, hmm.. normally time itself is not an element of bootstrap paradox. Also, considering the leaks were created the same exact date in both Worlds, the Apocalypses are out of sync. I think the Power Plant's location is affected by the time passage and that might be the reason for the activation. Torben perhaps opens the canister outside the Power Plant as you mentioned, it's outside the effects of the time passage.

Comment: @MovieMe Time is usually a factor though.  A bootstrap paradox is all about events and their relative timing, setting up a situation to allow those events to happen in the first place.  To get the paradox, the same series of events needs to happen.  This means that the same things must occur at the same places and times as they already had, or else things change, and you don't get the same outcome and therefore wouldn't lead to that event in the first place.  Open the barrels too early, and the apocalypse occurs before people can do everything that causes that apocalypse in the first place.

Comment: Then it creates a grandfather paradox where the event never happened.  To avoid such a paradox, things have to occur in the same time and place as they always have, to allow the exact same series of events to occur.  If that doesn't happen you don't have the loop at all.

Comment: @JMac, hang on. The predestination paradox is event based, its a _causal_ loop. Some thing or somebody needs to trigger events in the loop. Cause leads to effect and this leads back to the cause. Though it is known that opening the barrels at, say, 10:05 is the event, the apocalypse still needs to have a cause. 10:05 is not a cause but it is the time of the event. It's a fact that this apocalypse will always happen at 10:05 because it's predestined. But the time of the day is not a trigger, something else happening at 10:05 becomes the trigger. This applies to all causal loops in general.

Comment: Ex: John loses his wife in an accident in the past at 10:05 one morning. He goes back in time to save her and rushes to the spot .. at 10:05 he loses control of his car and smashes into his wife's car, killing her. This event is predestined. A paradox where the future event caused the past event. It will always happen at 10:05. But he cause for her death is his car, not 10:05.

Comment: Also, no matter what, in this DARK predestination loop, even if they tired the barrels can't be opened sooner, the flow of _events_ would not not allow it. Movies like Predestination, 12 Monkeys, Timecrimes, etc, show us how no matter what anyone tries, the events will always happen at that that specific time. They are locked because they already happened. But the trigger, is _not_ time, it is a person or a thing.

Comment: @MovieMe The issue with trying to tie it to a single event in Dark is that there are so many events that both get triggered by that apocalypse, and trigger it, that I don't see how you can point to any one trigger, besides the obvious one of opening the barrels.  But what I'm getting at is, because we are seeing the loop, we _have_ to see events in the time and location that perpetuates the loop.  The apocalypse has to happen at the right time and spot to cause itself.  Even in the examples you give, the trigger is the right events _at the right time_, or else you get no loop at all.

Comment: @JMac, true that. The time of the event is unalterable. They go to additional extents in the series to show that a gun refuses to fire if shot at the wrong moment at the wrong person. So the tins would probably refuse to open if they tried too soon ... maybe.

Comment: @MovieMe Yeah that's the kinda thing I was trying to get at.  I can't really say for sure that it couldn't have caused a disaster at some other time or location... but the way we see everything tied together I suspect it basically had to happen at the right time and place to happen at all.